# Как в Java проверить, пустой ли элемент в массиве?

Tags: java, массивы, null

Есть массив типа int. Туда занесены различные числа.
Организован цикл, который поочередно будет выводить числа.
Необходима проверка на то, есть ли в массиве пустой элемент, чтоб не выводить его.

Код на Java с ошибкой:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    if (num.length > 0 && num[i] != null) {
        System.out.print(num[i] + ", ");
    }
}
```

Comment: В массиве ``int[]`` не может содержаться ``null``. Что вы в даннном случае понимаете под пустым элементом?

Comment: Быть может изначально стоит использовать какой-нибудь `Set`, а не массив?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен не `int[]`, а массив с элементами ссылочного типа `Integer[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Для массива объектов можно использовать метод [`Objects.nonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull-java.lang.Object-):

```java
Integer[] arr = {1, null, 3, null, 5, null};

Arrays.stream(arr).filter(Objects::nonNull).forEach(System.out::println);
// 1
// 3
// 5
```

---

Если имеется массив примитивов `int[]`, тогда пустое значение в нем будет `0`, а не `null`:

```java
int[] arr = {1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0};

Arrays.stream(arr).filter(i -> i != 0).forEach(System.out::println);
// 1
// 3
// 5
```